# Page controller not displaying correctly

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The circles on my page control, which is in a xib, are being cut / trimmed slightly on an ipad non retina. The tops and right sides of the dots are missing a pixel or 2. Any ideas how to fix?

Here's a screenshot of the dots (look closely)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by a odd number division and that's why you see it only on non retina devices.  It would be useful to see the frame of your page control for both size and coordinates, there's an odd value within those that brings the component to be placed to a "half-pixel" when going to non-retina screens. Judging by the image you attached looks like  the origin.y is placed at a "half-pixel" value. Try to NSLog the frame and you'll probably see what I mean.

Hope it helps.